# How to generate a seed file based on existing data in postgresql via prisma orm?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have parsed some data about restaurants and loaded them to my local database. How can I generate a seed file based on existing data in db via prisma orm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a seed.js

connect to your local database,
after retrieving you can bulk insert the data to any supported database which prisma supports.